# How can I get AWS Chalice to use pyenv virtualenv python version?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, pyenv, chalice

I have a virtual environment create from `pyenv virtualenv 3.8.8 raai` which is active. When I install and then invoke `chalice` it is using the system installed python version.

How can I get the chalice command to use the pyenv specified/active python?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the `which python` output please ?

Comment: In the activated virtualenv, what does `cat \`which chalice\`` return in the terminal? Also what does `which python` return in the terminal?

Comment: It was indeed installed in a different environment and with missing `pyenv` path... the `chalice` command was hitting that. Thank all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ensuring Chalice is installed in your virtual environment, the chalice that is found in the path may have been installed in your other version of Python.

When your virtual environment is active, try reinstalling chalice in that virtenv:

`pip install chalice`